# How to get the path of the resources folder

Tags: java, html, netbeans

I am developing a java web application in Netbeans and I would like to know how to get the path of the following file, which I need to read. In the following image I indicate which is the route that I want to know.

[image: File]

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this using Servlets/JSP, Java Server Faces, or Spring?

Comment: Java Server Faces, i'm using PrimeFaces.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about in JSF, but in Servlets you ask the `ServletContext` to open a resource as stream for you... there might be something similar in JSF?